# Compiler error when building R-package using RcppArmadillo on win-builder

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I built an R-package using RcppArmadillo on a unix platform (Ubuntu 14.04). When running R CMD CHECK, I don't get any errors or warnings and everything works just fine. However, when I try to build windows binaries via win-builder, I get the following compiler error message:

```
/local330/lib -LD:/RCompile/recent/R/bin/i386 -lR
LD.o:LD.cpp:(.text+0x598): undefined reference to `ddot_'
LD.o:LD.cpp:(.text+0x8d3): undefined reference to `ddot_'
LD.o:LD.cpp:(.text+0x686b): undefined reference to `ddot_'
LD.o:LD.cpp:(.text+0x6af5): undefined reference to `ddot_'
```

In the file LD.cpp, I use the Armadillo function `arma::dot`. The top of the file looks like

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;
```

When trying to build on the Windows-PC of a colleague of mine, I get the same compiler error message. I suspect the linking to LAPACK/BLAS does not work properly, but I have no idea what I could do to fix this.

I also use `#include<BH.h>`, but this is in a different file.

*Edit*
I do not have a makevars or makevars.win file.

Here are the relevant parts of the DESCRIPTION file:

```
Package: ...
Title: ...
Version: 0.0.0
Author: ...
Maintainer: ...
Description: ...
Depends:
    R (>= 3.3.2)
License: GPL-3
LazyData: true
LinkingTo: Rcpp, RcppArmadillo, RcppProgress, BH
Imports:
    Rcpp (>= 0.12.8),
    RcppArmadillo (>= 0.7.500.0.0),
    purrr (>= 0.2.2),
    BH (>= 1.60.0-2),
    stats,
    utils
Suggests:
    knitr,
    testthat,
    rmarkdown,
    magrittr
VignetteBuilder: knitr
RoxygenNote: 5.0.1
SystemRequirements: C++11
```

And here is the function than most likely causes the problem:

```
arma::mat test(const arma::mat& X) {
  int n = X.n_rows;
  int m = X.n_cols;

  mat Xs(X.memptr(), n, m);
  vec pv = arma::conv_to< vec >::from(mean(Xs));
  for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    double p = pv(j);
    double s = sqrt(p * (1 - p));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      Xs(i, j) = (Xs(i, j) - p) / s;
    }
  }

  mat out(m, m);
  for (int i = 0; i < m - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < m; j++) {
      double tmp = pow(arma::dot(Xs.col(i), Xs.col(j)) / n, 2);
       out(i, j) = tmp;
       out(j, i) = tmp;
    }
    out(i, i) = pow(arma::dot(Xs.col(i), Xs.col(i)) / n, 2);
  }
  out(m - 1, m - 1) = pow(arma::dot(Xs.col(m - 1), Xs.col(m - 1)) / n, 2);
  return out;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the package's **DESCRIPTION** file to your question? Also, try to narrow down which of your functions is causing this error, and add that code to your question as well. Finally, does your **src/** directory contain either of **Makevars** or **Makevars.win**, and if so, what do they contain?

Comment: @nrussell I added the information you asked for. I do not have a Makevars / Makewars.win file in src/, could this be the cause of the error?

Comment: That surely is the error. _Look at the example package generated by `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()`_ and note the presence of `src/Makevars{,win}`.   This is documented.  You must have both,

Comment: I added Makevars and Makevars.win and it works (feeling ashamed), this was the problem. I generated the package skeleton with `devtools` and this is the first time I hear about the above two files. Thank you both for your help!

Comment: _`devtools` considered harmful_. You need `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()`, not `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`.  And until `devtools` knows that, stay away.

Comment: Glad you have it working.  There is, as always, a lot of documentation to look at -- but keep in mind that almost 300 _working CRAN packages with RcppArmadillo_ also give you reference examples.

Comment: I know Dirk, but sometimes I just don't know where to look for the solution when I don't even understand the problem ;).

Comment: @Dominik, also this is not an #rcpp11 problem. Entirely different package. (Removed tag.)